# How to hide specific text in a class using CSS?

Tags: css, hide

I have the following:

```
<h4 class="modal-title">Algebra I, Algebra II (2 free spaces)</h4>
```

I wish to hide "(2 free spaces)" only but still display the rest. How may I do so utilizing CSS only?

Final result should ONLY show "Algebra I, Algebra II".

Answer (score 0):

You can do so.

```
<h4 class="modal-title">Algebra I, Algebra II <span style="opacity:0;">(2 free spaces)</span></h4>
```

This code will hide the "(2 free spaces)".

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by making the whole text invisible and then rewrite it using :before or :after

This technique replace the whole text, not just a part of it. But yes, i'ts possible to replace text using CSS. Check:

```
.modal-title {
 font-size:0px;
}
.modal-title:before {
 font-size:12px;
 display:inline-block;
 content: "Algebra I, Algebra II"
}
```

Comment: So the content itself is dynamic. As the class suggests, it is a modal pop up based on which lesson you click. The "x free spaces" can be either 2 or 5. How can I create two different scenarios to catch if its 2 or 5 and only eliminate that. The class names can only change (for example: could be Geometry, Pre-Calc instead of Algebra I, Algebra II) but that has much more variability than just 2 or 5 free spaces.

Comment: Only using CSS this scenario seems impossible. Can be done by using javascript or changing html structure.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a span around `(2 free spaces)` with a `class` so that you can refrence it in your css:

```
<h4 class="modal-title">Algebra I, Algebra II <span class="hide">(2 free spaces)</span></h4>
```

Then, in your css you can hide it by targetting the span's `class` using `display: none`:

```
.hide {
  display: none
}
```

See working example below:

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<h4 class="modal-title">Algebra I, Algebra II <span class="hide">(2 free spaces)</span></h4>
```

If you cannot add a span to your HTML or don't know the size the size of your title, you can use the following javascript:

```js
let modal_title = document.querySelectorAll('.modal-title'); // get the modal title elements

modal_title.forEach(elem => { // loop over each element, where elem represents a given modal title
  let txt_title = elem.textContent; // get the text from that given modal title
  elem.innerHTML = txt_title.replace(/(\(\d+ free spaces\))/, "<span class='hide'>$1</span>"); // add the "hide" span around the title text using regex
});
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<h4 class="modal-title">Algebra I, Algebra II (2 free spaces)</h4>

<h4 class="modal-title">Alg I, Alg II (10 free spaces)</h4>
```